# Wordpress: RewriteRule does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitio/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sitio/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

In the Wordpress configuration I have:
[image]

But when I try to visualize the content of the page I get:[image]

It only works if I use the following URL:
http://www.kobsa.com.pe/sitio/**index.php**/about-us/

Comment: Is the .htaccess file in sitio directory?

Comment: It's Right. So is.

Comment: it's because you have RewriteRule . /sitio/index.php [L] as the last rule anything after that is the postname rule

Comment: And how should it be? That file was created by the same Wordpress.

Comment: Why 2 RewriteBase statements? Remove the first one

Comment: This is the currently the contents of my .htaccess file: https://ibb.co/gXbAa5

Answer (score 0):

1. Change permalinks to: `Plain`
2. Remove your .htaccess file
3. In your `wp-config.php` before the `That's all. Stop editing...` line add:

   define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/sitio');

   define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/sitio' );
4. Change permalinks to: `Post name`

And you're done.

Comment: config.php or wp-config.php ?

Comment: Right - `wp-config.php` - I've corrected the answer.

Comment: I added two lines that you indicated in the wp-config after "define ('WP_DEBUG', false);" Then I went to Wordpress and changed the permalinks to "Post Name". Then I rebooted the Apache server but it still shows me 404.

Comment: Has Wordpress recreated the .htaccess file in the `sitio` directory? This is the same directory where the `wp-config.php` is in?

Comment: Noup! It could not create it.

Comment: Maybe there's problem with the write access for the Apache in the `sitio` directory because Wordpress should recreate the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I already gave permissions to wordpress to create the .htaccess file, but anyway, it still does not apply the settings.